# Kafka Streams - Extracting Timestamp for List of Objects per record

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

What I want to achieve is to get a count of each message present in the record based on the timestamp present in the message. Each record consists of `List<Metric>` object. I would like to extract the timestamp for each metric and aggregate the metric based on the metric name.

**Metric**

```
public class Metric {

    String metric;
    Long timestamp;
    Double value;
}
```

**Custom Timestamp Extractor**

I have implemented this timestamp extractor that converts the record to a List object. And it currently fetches the first timestamp that does the windowing for this ArrayList.

```
public class EventTimestampExtractor implements TimestampExtractor {

    public long extract(ConsumerRecord<Object, Object> record, long previousTimeStamp) {
        try {
            // Have a ListSerde in place to deserialize the record to a  List<Metric> object.
            final List<Metric> value = (List<Metric>) record.value();
            final Metric metric = value.get(0); // Returning the first timestamp from the metric list. 
            return metric.getTimestamp();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // If there is an exception, return back the event time.
            return record.timestamp();
        }
    }
}
```

**Topology**

Once I fetch the list, I perform a FlatTransform to transform this List and perform aggregations based on the flattened List.

```
final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream<String, List<Metric>> stream = builder.stream(inputTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(),new MetricListSerde()));

TimeWindows windows = TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).grace(Duration.ofSeconds(2));

stream.filter((key, value) -> value != null)
                .flatTransform(() -> new MetricsTransformer()) // Flat transforming the list to single metrics
                .groupByKey()
                .windowedBy(windows)
                .count()
                .toStream()
                .to("output-topic");
```

**Metric List Example** - If you notice there is a single metric and 3 counts ( 2 betweeen 0-10 and 1 after 10 seconds)

```
[{  "metric": "metric1.count",
    "timestamp": 1,
    "value": 30
},{
    "metric": "metric1.count",
    "timestamp": 2,
    "value": 30
}, {
    "metric": "metric1.count",
    "timestamp": 15,
    "value": 30
}]
```

My window is 10 seconds and I would like to do a get the count for the metric. My **current result** looks like -

```
Window{startMs=0, endMs=10} and Value metric: metric1.count value: 3  aggregator: count interval: "10s"}
```

**Expected Result** -

```
Window{startMs=0, endMs=10} and Value metric: metric1.count value: 2  aggregator: count interval: "10s"}
Window{startMs=10, endMs=20} and Value metric: metric1.count value: 1  aggregator: count interval: "10s"}
```

Apologies for the long question, but is there any way to extract multiple timestamps from a single record that contains a Collection of messages?

Kafka Streams version - 2.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TimestampExtractor` does not help for your use case, because it can only give you a single timestamp. Using `flatMap()` all output records inherit the timestamp of the input record.

If you need to modify timestamp on-the-fly, you need to use `transform()` to implement the "flat map". For each input records, you can call `context.forward()` multiple times to do the actually flat mapping (you can just `return null;` at the end to not emit any additional records). In each `forward()` call, you can set a new timestamp via `To.all().withTimestamp(...)`:

```java
public KeyValue transform(K key, V value) {
    for (...) {
       context.forward(newKey, newValue, To.all().withTimestamp(newTimestamp);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: you are awesome :)